# Displaying a limited portion of a css sprite as background in a form input element

Tags: html, css, image, forms, css-sprites

I have a form input-field (a search bar) and I'm using a sprite sheet of icons as a background to the input field.

Is there a way to set the image sprite as the input field background, but limit the viewable space of the background/sprite to avoid sprite bleeding? Ideally without editing the sprite image itself.

Here is the desired result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzJA6.png

And the current result I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/guFOE.png

The input field has the desired padding and image sprite. However, I get sprite bleeding due to the closeness of the images in the sprite vs the input field size. Is there a way to fix this using CSS alone?

My input field css is roughly:

```
#search-field{
            padding-left: 50px; /*numerical values aren't exact*/
            background: url("images/icon_sprite.png") 5px -15px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the image you used for the sprite and your html?

Comment: I'm always using the abstract element :before (or :after) when I do this, you can then set the height of that element to have it the same as the sprite background image.

Comment: sprites are the ancient way of doing what you want, switch to icon fonts